# how to match a server database with with local database for iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi friend
  can any one tell me that i have web server there i have create the database for store some value for registration form the value was save in webserver this is working good.

but now that data coming in json format and now i have fetch json value and save in to the local database which is same as the webserver database both the side same table and same colume name is there how can i do this in iphone application special for login page and other data also.
   and how to write the query for this sitution help me friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can'nt match the local & remote database by using  sql query,
you need to fetch the remote data using WEB API's then compare with your local database (local data will be accessed through sql query ).

Comment: but how friend can u give me some small code for this or som link bec this my first project on yhis application